24.04 LTS || Unable to install Tomcat 9 - "Package 'tomcat9' has no installation candidate"
I'm trying to install Tomcat 9 on my Ubuntu system using `*
sudo apt-get install tomcat9
but I keep running into the following error:

monirul@nitacl-Veriton-Series:~$ sudo apt-get install tomcat9  Reading
package lists... Done  Building dependency tree... Done  Reading state
information... Done Package tomcat9 is not available, but is referred
to by another package.  This may mean that the package is missing, has
been obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Package
'tomcat9' has no installation candidate

Here's what I've tried so far:
sudo apt update

Searching for alternative package names (e.g., tomcat9.0, tomcat-9) using apt-cache search tomcat
System Information:
Ubuntu version: 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat
Architecture: LAMP
Could anyone please point me in the right direction? Is there a specific repository I need to enable or a different approach to installing Tomcat 9?
Thanks in advance for your help!

tomcat9 is only available till 23.10, with 24.04 it's tomcat10
